# Xamarin.Essentials Share.RequestAsync() dont working on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i'm having some trouble trying to share some pdfs with xamarin.Essentials on iOS, method is working as expected in Android but when i run in iOS the method is called with no error but nothing happens, Share menu don't open and the page still running with no error, i'll post some code below:

PCL View.xaml (where share button is in)

```
<ContentPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             BackgroundColor="#6f7d8b" 
             x:Class="SeusPPPs.PDFViewer.View"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SeusPPPs">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid  RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Padding="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="COMPARTILHAR" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SHARE" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Padding="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="FECHAR" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Close" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

            <controls:PdfWebView
            x:Name="PdfView" 
            Grid.Row="1"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

code-behind share event

```
public void SHARE(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_filepath == null)
                return;
            try
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest() {
                         Title = "Compartilhar seu PPP",
                         File = new ShareFile(_filepath)
                    });

                });

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Load PDF Method, working fine on both ios and android

```
private void CarregarPdf(string id)
        {

            var dependency = DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileProvider>();

            if (dependency == null)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Erro ao carregar dependencia", "Dependencia não encontrada", "OK");

                return;
            }

            var localPath = string.Empty;

            string url = "apiurl" + id;

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var pdfStream = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url)).Result;
                localPath =
                    Task.Run(() => dependency.SaveFileToDisk(pdfStream, $"{fileName}.pdf")).Result;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(localPath))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error baixar PDF", "não foi possivel encontrar o arquivo", "OK");

                return;
            }
            _filepath = localPath;
            PdfView.Uri = localPath;
        }
```

//EDIT

I did notice the problem is only on physical devices, you can reproduce the error using this repository [Github](https://github.com/gojnimer147/ShareTest)

Comment: Did you add a `breakpoint` in the `SHARE` method and check if `Share.RequestAsync` executed when you click share button.

Comment: From where `CarregarPdf(string id)` method is called? Can you put break point and check if that is called after tapping label?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yeah, it's being called every click

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya from Page ctor, pdf is loading just fine in the webview.

Comment: Can you create a sample project on Github that we can possibly download and try on our machines?

Comment: @Saamer i'll create a sample project

Comment: Also can you try to remove the await from the “await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest()“ line and see what happens ? It might be calling the code on a non UI thread and hence never gets shown. It’s a common problem.

Comment: i'm building the project here, something curious happened, share is working fine in Emulator but still doing nothing in Physical device, i'll try to remove the await.

Comment: i'm getting these errors aswell

Thread started:  #11
CoreGraphics PDF has logged an error. Set environment variable "CG_PDF_VERBOSE" to learn more.
2019-12-16 11:30:06.853 App1.iOS[8541:19498675] WARNING: This app's CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is not a string value. This can lead to unexpected results at runtime. Please change CFBundleDevelopmentRegion in your Info.plist to a string value.
Thread started:  #12

Comment: @Sammer here's the repository, https://github.com/gojnimer147/ShareTest

Comment: When I test your project, there is no response after I click the open pdf button. I would suggest you to check whether the _filepath you get is valid in physical device.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT you can try with another URL using the entry, i did test the path in the physical device, pdf is loading OK and the share is being called with the right filepath

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT kill and reopen the app, then click the "open pdf" button right away without clicking the entry, i found a bug in the entry, i'll fix this soon as i can

Comment: OK, I connect my iPhone to wifi and the pdf loads well. When I click the 
COMPARTILHAR label, the share menu shows perfectly. Everything works well on my side with your code. I use iPhone with iOS 12.2.

Comment: Maybe it's an version problem?, i'm using 13.2.3 on my ipad

Comment: It also works well on my ipad simulator with iOS13. I don't have a real ipad to test so far. Can you change another device to test?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i'm uploading the real app in testflight for the customer, then i'll try 
to open in iphone

Comment: Ok, I think it will work. You can also debug in iphone.

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to Xamarin 4.8, the problem still existed.  But when I added a dummy PresentationSourceBounds, it seems to have fixed the issue?
Note:  I had not tried this on earlier versions of Xamarin.

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
  Title = result.Data.Name,
  File = new ShareFile(temporaryFile),
  PresentationSourceBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1) // Fixes iPad share option
});
```

Comment: Still an issue in 2021, but the solution works.

Comment: This solution does not work for me (iOS version 13.0)